# Generate a random site colour scheme using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a small site and thought it would be quirky if the site adopted a random colour scheme on each visit - meaning each time a user visited the site, they would see a slightly different version.

I have attempted doing this using JavaScript but the site generates a new colour on each page visit...

Any help would be great - if it can be done solely using JS that is?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Generate random colour for the header of the site...

    let colours = [
        '#F8E71C',
        '#1cf8b1',
        '#1cb1f8',
        '#c21cf8',
        '#f81c3a',
    ];

    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length) + 1;

    let header = $('.site-head');
    let cardColour = $('.card__border');

    localStorage.setItem("siteTheme", colours[randomNumber]);

    if (localStorage.getItem("siteTheme")) {
        header.css({
            backgroundColor: localStorage.getItem("siteTheme"),
        });

        cardColour.css({
            backgroundColor: localStorage.getItem("siteTheme"),
        }); 
    }

});
```

Comment: try with cookie http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: your code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you generate a random color and then set it in localStorage, **every time**.

I refactored your code into functions with an initial check.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    let header = $('.site-head');
    let cardColour = $('.card__border');

    if (localStorage.getItem("siteTheme")) {
        setColorScheme();
    } else {
        createColorScheme();
    }

    function createColorScheme() {
        let colours = [
            '#F8E71C',
            '#1cf8b1',
            '#1cb1f8',
            '#c21cf8',
            '#f81c3a',
        ];

        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length) + 1;

        localStorage.setItem("siteTheme", colours[randomNumber]);

        setColorScheme();
    }

    function setColorScheme() {
        header.css({
            backgroundColor: localStorage.getItem("siteTheme"),
        });

        cardColour.css({
            backgroundColor: localStorage.getItem("siteTheme"),
        });
    }

});
```

Note: I think you have an error in the random generator part, sometimes the random color becomes `undefined`, I think it's because of the `+ 1`.

Comment: Yeah, I changed that to + 0, and it works in Chrome, however in Safari it just shows a white background with an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'header'

Comment: Never mind, I discovered that Safari does not allow let... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Useful site for checking things like that: http://caniuse.com/#search=let if you didn't know it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check localStorage **before** storing another random color sheme?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Generate random colour for the header of the site...

    let colours = [
        '#F8E71C',
        '#1cf8b1',
        '#1cb1f8',
        '#c21cf8',
        '#f81c3a',
    ];

    let header = $('.site-head');
    let cardColour = $('.card__border');

    if (!localStorage.getItem("siteTheme")) {
        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length) + 1;

        localStorage.setItem("siteTheme", colours[randomNumber]);
    }

    header.css({
        backgroundColor: localStorage.getItem("siteTheme"),
    });

    cardColour.css({
        backgroundColor: localStorage.getItem("siteTheme"),
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - however when I use that code I get a reference error to header: Uncaught ReferenceError: header is not defined

Comment: And you should remove`+1` from random number genertor since JS arrays are 0-based.